# Django output 1 field from a model within another table

Tags: django

I have 2 models -

```
class InsName(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name = "Insurer/Broker")
    alias = models.TextField(max_length=80, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}, {self.alias}'
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('insurer-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

class Development(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    logno = models.CharField(validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^(SCTASK|CDLI)[0-9]{7}', message='Please enter a valid log number', code='nomatch')], max_length=13)
    insurer = models.ForeignKey(InsName, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False, verbose_name="Client")
    policy = models.ManyToManyField(Policy, blank=True)
```

on my template I am outputting a list of Developments but where **insurer** is output I just want the **name** part to output. I need to retain the alias as it is used in other templates that also calls in **InsName**.

I thought I could use a substring before comma method in the template but I cant see that such a thing exists. Is this possible? If not any tips on how I can achieve this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: if `development` is one object in your list (assuming a forloop): `{{development.insurer.name}}` is just the name. Is that not what you want?

Comment: Cheers Dirkgroten, I cant believe it was as simple as that!!

Comment: See also the answer (and my comment) below, adding a `select_related` will avoid you hitting the db separately for each object in your list.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do it like this using [F](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations) (apart from comment of **@dirkgroten**):

```
queryset = Development.objects.all().annotate(insurer_name=F('insurer__name'))
```

And use it in template:

```
{% for item in queryset %}
  {{ item.insurer_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Adding an annotation for something straightforward like this doesn't help readability in my opinion. It helps avoiding multiple queries to the database. However, adding a `select_related('insurer')` to the QuerySet would achieve the same and still let you access `item.insurer.name`.

Comment: I agree with you. But it might help when it comes to dealing with multiple nested FKs ie `F('something__foo__bar__name')`.

Comment: In that case yes.